# SEVERE: Unable to load the hibernate config properties file

Tags: java, junit, testcase

Hi I have a test class in my UI project. It gets terminated showing the following message :

SEVERE: Unable to load the hibernate config properties file

I am working on java, RAD 7.5, portal server 6.1.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your hibernate.cfg.xml file is at the root of your classpath. If you're running from a JAR, it should be in there without any path in front. If you're using maven, it should be in src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml. If you need further assistance, please leave a comment.

Comment: The way you show that, on this site, is by accepting the answer and voting it up